# Jigsaw Logic: Opheodrys Vernalis

Tags: tiling, jigsaw-puzzle

[image]

### Challenge:

Given unlimited copies of each of the above type of puzzle piece, create a $9\times 9$ square which features a picture of snake.

### Rules:

- There must be only one snake, with a head at one end and a tail at the other.
- Pieces may be rotated, but not flipped.
- A piece with one straight edge must be placed at the the square's edge.
- A piece with two straight edges must be placed at the square's corner.
- Some pieces may be used many times, some only once, others not at all.

---

If my calculations are correct, <strike>the solution is essentially unique. Specifically, there are two solutions up to rotation, but the only difference between them is that the head and tail pieces are swapped.</strike>

**Edit:** I was wrong, this puzzle is under specified, there are at least 3 distinct solutions.

Comment: So is there a reason you decided to drive the compulsives insane with that second row? I mean, either center the whole row or add a nice 15th piece with only straight edges.. That said, great puzzle :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few solutions, but we're only asked to find one of them, so here one is:

> It looks like *most* of the puzzle is constrained - I believe I only get to make two assumptions (and different choices there will yield the remaining solutions).
>
>  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Just posting this for the sake of completeness.

There are four solutions to this puzzle. One of them is in Zerris's answer, another is below. Given any solution, you can get a different one by swapping the tail and head pieces, which gives all four.

> [image]